Authenticating Domain - DNS Validation, CNAME record not working
Hi so I have purchased my first domain and at first I set it up to point to an S3 static website. I set it up for http and it was working great. After this I used AWS ACM to generate a certificate to enable https, I chose to use DNS validation for the cert. After the cert was issued I added the CNAME record to my Namecheap domain as shown but now when visiting the site using https it just is stuck loading forevor before I get a no response error. Please help me understand what is going wrong

Namecheap DNS Records

Tried to append CNAME DNS Record from AWS Certificate to NameCheap domain records, site is not loading when using https only works on http.
I have seen that it may take up to 48 hours to come into effect, I have made the changes ~32 hours ago now and am starting to sweat lol.
